# town with a spanish feel / vibe

Tags: grammar

Is it idiomatically correct to say
1.) "a town with a spanish feel"
2.) "a town with a spanish vibe"?
Are 1.) and 2.)  slightly different in meaning?

Comment: Not sure that you've chosen the right tag for your question; the two sentences are the same grammatically.

Comment: "Vibe" is in an informal register and is somewhat outdated - it belongs more to the era of "hippies".